# Where does the Liferay portal-ext.properties go?

Tags: glassfish, liferay, glassfish-3, liferay-6

Below is my folder hierarchy. Where does the portal-ext.properties go?

```
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\liferay
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it in WEB-INF/classes folder of your liferay application.
Probably C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\liferay\WEB-INF\classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more clean location you can put it into the main folder of liferay. e.g.: **C:\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2**